# Build a Vue library to run in a non-Vue app

Tags: vue.js, build

I need to create a Vue Library out of a Vue app. I need it such that I can include it and run the entire app on a site that does not have Vue installed. That is, the library needs to be standalone.

Following the docs on the vue site it says...

**Note on Vue Dependency**

*In web component mode, Vue is externalized. This means the bundle will not bundle Vue even if your code imports Vue. The bundle will assume Vue is available on the host page as a global variable.*

I want the Vue to be built 'without' any dependency to Vue. My host page cannot have Vue as a global anything.

In old school parlance I want the app 'compiled' to js. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [Rollup](https://rollupjs.org/) or [Webpack](http://webpack.js.org/) to bundle your Vue.js library as [UMD](https://github.com/umdjs/umd) module which is essentially a fully contained code without any external dependency.

For example, when you are [authoring library using Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/guides/author-libraries/), typically, you would have:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/lib.js',

  output: {

    // Bundle will be generated in `dist` folder
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),

    // This will the name of your library's bundled file
    filename: 'lib-bundle.js',

    // Your own library will be available globally with `LibName`
    library: 'LibName',

    // Ensure to generate UMD bundle
    libraryTarget: 'umd'
  },
  externals: { /* MAKE SURE THAT EXTERNALS IS EMPTY */ }
};
```

In the above config, since config `externals` is empty, Webpack will bundle all the dependencies including `Vue` and others into your final library bundle so that your host environment need not have Vue available.

Comment: Thank you Harsharl..  I gave you an up vote but I don't have the rep on this site for it to show..  I have gone with webpack and it it working a treat. 

Rollup looks great however. Maybe next project.

Comment: @DoblyTufnell, That is ok. Glad that it helped you. Considering [accepting the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) if it works for you.